# Example in React about how to implement D3's .transition().duration().ease() etc

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

All:

Like the title said, I am trying to build a component which can accept transition / duration / ease props to implement a animated transition for a data visualization project( the main usage is for switching data set).

I am not sure if a component is correct way to achieve this in React, if not please advise any way to do this in React.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate thing with trying to use these two libraries together is the way they interact with the DOM.

D3 directly select elements, then binds data to those elements, and adds, updates, or removes elements based on the dataset.

React likes to have everything represented in it's virtual DOM and doesn't like any changes to the actual DOM without it's consent.

Some people will approach this problem by disabling certain lifecycle methods and using functional side effects to accomplish D3's methods.

```
class ExpenseComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // wrap element in d3
    this.d3Node = d3.select(this.getDOMNode());
    this.d3Node.datum(this.props.data)
      .call(ExpenseVisualization.enter);
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data.update) {
      // use d3 to update component
      this.d3Node.datum(nextProps.data)
        .call(ExpenseVisualization.update);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },

  componentDidUpate() {
    this.d3Node.datum(this.props.data)
      .call(ExpenseVisualization.update);
  },

  render() {
    // …
  }
}
```

While this works for some cases, you're losing out on the benefits of passing state to any children components that component may be rendering.

I would suggest researching some of these approaches of how people have tried to tackle the issue, to see the root of the problem.

Also, feel free to try out this library my friends and I made that allows you to plug in your existing D3 code as is, and returns React components, and handles transitions, animations, timers, etc.

http://react-d3-library.github.io/

Always looking for more feedback!